# VBA: Printing JSON to Text File Includes Double Quotes

Tags: json, excel, string, vba

The following code

```
Dim theJSON As String
theJSON = "{""docType"":""DRAFT"",""riskState"":""NY""}"

theFileName = "C:\test.json"

Open theFileName For Output As #1
Write #1, theJSON 'jsonSerialization
Close #1
```

produces an output like this:

> "{""docType"":""DRAFT"",""riskState"":""NY""}"

I cannot figure out how to stop the VBA string syntax from printing into the file (escape quotes and leading/trailing quotes).

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe `Write` text qualifies the output for CSV. `Print` should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VBA has two different sets of functions for text file handling:

`Write #` and `Input #` are intended to be used with "structured" files (.csv), and use text qualified data - any `String` or `Variant` with a string subtype has double quotes escaped as `""`, and the entire thing is surrounded in quotes.

`Print #` and `Input(number, #filenumber)` are intended to be used with "unstructured" files.

The solution is to use `Print` instead of `Write`:

```
Dim theJSON As String
theJSON = "{""docType"":""DRAFT"",""riskState"":""NY""}"

theFileName = "C:\test.json"

Dim handle As Integer
handle = FreeFile
Open theFileName For Output As #handle
Print #handle, theJSON 'jsonSerialization
Close #handle
```

Note that you should always use the `FreeFile` function to return an open file handle instead of hard coding the numbers - this avoids the possibility of handle collisions and unintended file access.